# ios - how to create a check-list ux experience?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am looking to create a user experience that is a basic checklist.  But I do not really see that in the xCode controls.  Could someone please advise me how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a tableview with a checkbox in the first column and a textview in the second column?

Comment: @trojanfoe I never made a thing like that before. Is it relatively complicated? I am not too good with ios programming still.

Comment: No I don't think it will be hard.  Find some tableview samples and then find out how to control the checkbox/text cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you customize a UITableView and disable selecting (table_view.allowsSelection = NO)

In your custom table, you'd have custom rows which contain a button (a customized UIButton) that acts as a checklist. You can implement the UI feedback of checking a checkbox via the click event of that UIButton (it would toggle to checked on/off state when clicked) and in your code, you would track which of the rows are checked off.

Hope that is clear, feel free to ask more